# Как называется этот трюк с динамическим созданием имени переменной ${'foo' . $x}?

Tags: php

```
$x = 'bar';
${'foo' . $x} = 'abc';
echo $foobar; // abc
```

Как и почему это работает?

Comment: это не трюк, скобки используются для доступа к динамическим свойствам объектов и в т..ч переменным.

Comment: Раздел [Переменные переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) почитайте

Comment: @teran Спасибо, товарищ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**КАК ЭТО РАБОТАЕТ:**

[Переменная переменной, или Динамическая переменная](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) использует строку, выражение или значение другой переменой как собственное имя:

```
$x = 'bar';
$$x = 'baz'; // $$x -> $ + bar -> $bar
// теперь в куче имён появилось новое - bar со значением baz
```

То, что новая переменная теперь доступна легко проверить:

```
$x = 'bar';
$$x = 'baz';
echo $bar; // baz
echo $$x;  // baz
```

Возможно присвоение по цепочке, с использованием нескольких переменных:

```
$x = 'bar';
$$x = 'foo';
$$$x = 'baz'; // $ + foo как ( $ + bar как значение $x )
echo $foo; // baz
echo $$$x; // baz
```

Если необходимо создать переменную с использованием строковых выражений или нескольких переменных (и с и без строк), их заключают в фигурные скобки `{'string'}`

```
$x = 'bar';
${$x.'bar'} = 'baz'; // $ + {bar как значение $x + bar как строка}
echo $barbar;        // baz
echo ${$x.'bar'};    // baz
```

Можно подставлять пользовательские функции:

```
function bar() {
    return 'bar';
}

$x = 'bar';
${$x.'bar'} = 'baz'; // $ + {bar как значение $x + bar как строка}
echo $barbar;        // baz
echo ${$x . bar()};  // baz
```

и конструкции языка:

```
$bar = 'BAR';
$x = 'bar';
${$x.'bar'} = 'baz'; // $ + {bar как значение $x + bar как строка}
echo $barbar;                // baz
echo ${$x.strtolower($bar)}; // baz
```

Стоит упомянуть переменные переменных при работе с массивами. Для тех, кто мануал читать не будет:

```
$bar = array('bar');
$x = 'bar';
${$x.$bar[0]} = 'baz';
echo $barbar; // baz
```

Последний нюанс, на который хотелось бы обратить внимание - т.к. переменные в php это ссылки на значения в куче, удаление переменной донора после создания переменной переменной не влияет на её состояние.

```
$x = 'bar';
$$x = 'baz';
unset($x);
echo $bar; // baz
echo $$x;  // Undefined variable
```

**ПОЧЕМУ ЭТО РАБОТАЕТ:**

потому, что гладиолус ;)

Comment: "_можно подставлять пользовательские функции и конструкции языка_" = в фигурных скобках может быть указано любое _выражение_

Comment: вообще крутая фича